# Flask-SQLAlchemy not creating my tables

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy and for some reason when i run my **`create_db.py`** only the migration table is created.
I tried it from python terminal with `from modules import db,models` then running **`db.create_all()`** but it still gives the same result.

this is my **`models.py`**.

```
from __init__ import db
from datetime import datetime

class Batch(db.Model):
    __tablename__='batch'
    batch_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    #total = db.Column(db.Integer)
    success = db.Column(db.Integer)
    failure = db.Column(db.Integer)
    folder = db.Column(db.String(15))
    email = db.Column(db.String(20))
    detail = db.relationship('Conversion', backref='details',lazy='dynamic')
    platform = db.relationship('Platform', backref='pub_data', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __init__(self,batch_id,success,failure,folder,email):
        self.batch_id = batch_id
        self.success = success
        self.failure = failure
        self.folder = folder
        self.email = email

class Conversion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'conversion'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    batch_id = db.Column(db.String,db.ForeignKey('batch.batch_id'))
    file_names = db.Column(db.String)
    status = db.Column(db.String(6))
    error = db.Column(db.Text)
    res_prop = db.Column(db.Integer)        

    def __init__(self,batch_id,file_names,status,res_prop,error=None):
        self.batch_id = batch_id
        self.file_names = file_names
        self.status = status
        self.error = error
        self.res_prop = res_prop

class Platform(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'platform'
    id= db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    batch_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('batch.batch_id'))
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self,batch_id,title):
        self.batch_id = batch_id
        self.title = title
        self.pub_date = datetime()
```

And here is my **`create_db.py`**

```
from modules import models
from modules import db
from migrate.versioning import api
from modules.default_config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI , SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
import os.path

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

Comment: There is no files in the versions directory? You got any errors?

Comment: @OrDuan No errors. the versions directory contains only __init__.py no other files. Though other migration files are created when i run migrate.py

Comment: try to import you models individually(from  modules import models.Batch - or somthing like that)

Comment: I tried that too but did not work. The issue is resolved now i had to import app from modules instead of `__init__` in models.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on changing

```
from __init__ import db
```

to

```
from modules import db
```

in models.py it worked.
when running flask application from outside package one needs to import everything from the package itself and not the individual modules.